# Echo out all images in a directory?

Tags: php

I am trying to echo out all of the images in a folder directory with a couple of exceptions/ignores.

This is working ok apart from it also echoes out a blank photo for every photo it echoes out?
why is this happening can someone please show me where I'm going wrong thanks.

```
<?php
$dirname = "./data/photos/".$profile_id."/";
$images = scandir($dirname);
$ignore = Array("_cover.jpg", "_default.jpg");

foreach($images as $curimg){
    if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
        echo "<img src='./data/photos/".$profile_id."/$curimg'/ class=\"profile_photos\"><br>\n";
    };
}     
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have an extra slash after your image source:

```
    echo "<img src='./data/photos/".$profile_id."/$curimg'/ class=\"profile_photos\"><br>\n";
//--------------------------------------------------------^ here
```

This may be interefering with how the browser parses the DOM and causing an extra image to appear.

Also, small suggestion, try using this line instead:

```
    echo "<img src='".$dirname.$curimg."' class=\"profile_photos\"><br>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure that `$curimg` is actually a jpg file:

```
    if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore) && preg_match("/\.jpg$/i", $curimg)) {
```

`scandir` returns not just files but subdirectories, including `.` and `..`.